# how to scan VIN barcode in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, barcode, scanning, vin

Iv been looking all over the internet for an add-on or program to add to visual studio nothing.

My Question is is there any way at all to have a VIN barcode scanner in Visual studio 2010. Any sample code or tutorial will help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VIN numbers are in the Code39 barcode format. So you really just need hardware capable of scanning a barcode. A cheap USB barcode scanner is about 20USD.

Then in VS, you just create a simple form with a text box. When the text box has focus, scanning a bar code will result in the text represented by that bar code (in your case a VIN) to appear in the text box just as if you had typed it in.

Also, if you want to go the other direction and generate bar codes in Code39, MSDN has a nice sample in C# [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Code39-Barcode-Control-For-a5bb8841).

Comment: sorry, i didnt explain a bit of information. I need to scan a image that i upload. So the usb barcode scanner is a great idea. just for what im working on it won't work.

But your second part really does help me alot, thanks alot for the information sir/miss

Comment: OK, then what you're talking about is optical character reading from an image (OCR). This might help --> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10734/Reading-Barcodes-from-an-Image-II

Comment: and this will do scans on a VIN code? im looking at the coding now and looking around the internet. don't i need a different scanner for VIN then for 39code??

Comment: If what you want is to turn a barcode into the text it represents, you need a barcode scanner (e.g., a physical device). If what you want is an image that you will then perform OCR on in order to recognize characters within that image, what you want is a camera (or document scanner or other image capturing device) plus some OCR software. If you already have an image of a VIN, then you just need to OCR it.

Comment: okey that works then, Thanks again for taking the time to help me